# How can I run a python script more than once in the same IDLE shell, without the shell closing and reopening?

Tags: python, python-3.x, shell, sublimetext3, python-idle

I want to use Sublime Text to write python scripts, but run them in IDLE.

So far I've created a build system like this:

```
{
    "cmd": ["/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/idle3", "-r", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "*.py",
    "selector": "source.python",
    "env": {"PYTHONIOENCODING": "utf-8"}
}
```

This successfully runs the script in an IDLE shell. But when I run the script again, it closes the shell windows and reopens it.

I want to run the script in the same window as the first. It should only create a new window if there isn't already a shell open. This is the same way it works if you were to use the IDLE script writing window and run it there; it doesn't close and reopen the window.

I'm using a Mac by the way.

The IDLE Docs have [this section on command line usage](https://docs.python.org/3/library/idle.html#command-line-usage) but I can't see anywhere about how I can do what I want. It just says "-r" is run. There is no run in an already opened shell.

Could anyone nudge me in the right direction for how I can do this please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot currently do what you want.  SublimeText asks macOS to start IDLE in python after putting the command-line arguments ('-r' and filename) jin sys.args.  When IDLE starts, it reads sys.args.  After that, there is no way for SublimeText to talk to IDLe.

What I could and might someday do is to add an option *in IDLE* to re-run the '-r' file, if any, when restarting the Shell with Shell=>Restart on the menu.  You could then save in SublimeText and rerun in IDLE.  Would that be better than the current situation?

Comment: NB: In case you haven't read his profile, Terry is a core Python developer focused on IDLE. Nothing like hearing it from the source!

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Adding a restart option would be better than the current situation. But it's not a big deal at all. I just wanted it to be more similar to how IDLE works with its own script windows. It's sometimes useful to see previous outputs and not have them automatically cleared each time I run the script.